# Class cannot be resolved to a type - Import Project

Tags: java, eclipse, import

Sadly i wasn't able to find something similar in the searching result.

I have imported a project from github to my local git-folder. Then i have imported the project to my own project with "Java Build-Path -> Projects-> Add".

Then many errors occured in my project and for example the import

import dna.graph.datastructures.DataStructure.ListType;

says: The import dna cannot be resolved to a type.

The curious thing is, if i point the mouse to a underlined classname, it suggets to import the exact class from the linked project.

In other word, eclipse knows about the project, but the import doesn't fit.

Comment: If i do "Project -> Clean" the redlines under the classnames disappear for 2-3 seconds, but the they are back again.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the correct version of Java in your project?

Comment: I am using jre1.8.0_20 in both projects. Only classes from the imported project are underlined

Comment: possible duplicate of [Import Jar file into eclipse fails - cannot be resolved to a type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216626/import-jar-file-into-eclipse-fails-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)

Comment: No, the problem mentioned there, is not similar to my problem

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty much like the problem mentioned here: http://philip.yurchuk.com/software/eclipse-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type-error/

But none of the tips there fixed my problem.